# Casting container of shared_ptr<Base> back to shared_ptr<Derived>

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

There are many references to this on the stack by I'm missing the last bit: casting.

I have a Base class and a set of derived ones

```
class Base
{
public:
Base ();
virtual ~Base () = default;
};

class Derived1
{
public:
Derived1 ();
virtual ~Derived1 () = default;
};

class Derived2
{
public:
Derived2 ();
virtual ~Derived2 () = default;
};
```

And I have a top layer class with a container of derived class objects

```
class Top
{
public:
Top ();
virtual ~Top () = default;
const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>& container () const {return m_container;};
private:
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>> m_container;
};
```

where the container is filled up as

```
for (...){
   std::shared_ptr<Base> el;
   if (condition1) 
   {std::shared_ptr<Derived1> tmp_el = std::make_shared<Derived1>();
   el = tmp_el;}
   else if (condition2) 
   {std::shared_ptr<Derived2> tmp_el = std::make_shared<Derived1>();
   el = tmp_el;}
   m_container.push_back(el);
}
```

Now in my `main` I have a `Top` object and I'd like to read back the vector of derived objects. How should I cast back the `std::shared_ptr<Base>` elements to derived ones? (I have a way to distinguish the cases which I didn't include here for sake of simplicity).

Bonus question: is the way I am filling the container the best one actually?

Comment: why do you need to cast back to the derived type in the first place? Polymorphism via inheritance shines when you do not need to know the type, ie you are actually doing poylmorphism. Otherwise `std::variant` or others might be more appropriate to retrieve the actual type

Comment: [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived1>(el)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast)

Comment: Regarding the second question, you could just do `m_container.push_back(std::make_shared<Derived1>())`. That is, no need to use `el` or `tmp_el`.